# ASP.NET Rijndael Encryption Error - Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm

Tags: asp.net, encryption, cryptography, rijndaelmanaged

I can't seem to get past this problem, I've created what I assume to be a 256-bit key using the random generator at [GRC](https://www.grc.com/passwords.htm) and combined that with my IV. I keep getting the error below:

***Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.***

Any help is gratefully received, here is the code I am using to Encrypt/Decrypt:

```
Private Function Rijndael(ByVal sInput As String, ByVal bEncrypt As Boolean) As String
    ' Setup the Key and Initialization Vector.
    Dim byteKey As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("C3CA193570B26E5C3CBB50FD805A0E23BAFFABA135E82C41517EEDCB9B7C90AC")
    Dim byteIV As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("c+O2r)J~?L:$]u[2")
    ' Create an instance of the encyrption algorithm. 
    Dim _rijndael As New RijndaelManaged()
    ' Create an encryptor using our key and IV 
    Dim transform As ICryptoTransform
    If bEncrypt Then
        transform = _rijndael.CreateEncryptor(byteKey, byteIV)
    Else
        transform = _rijndael.CreateDecryptor(byteKey, byteIV)
    End If
    ' Create the streams for input and output 
    Dim msOutput As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    Dim msInput As New CryptoStream(msOutput, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    ' Feed data into the crypto stream. 
    msInput.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sInput), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sInput).Length)
    ' Flush crypto stream. 
    msInput.FlushFinalBlock()
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(msOutput.ToArray)
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C3CA193570B26E5C3CBB50FD805A0E23BAFFABA135E82C41517EEDCB9B7C90AC` is hex code for a 256-bit-long bitstream.

But `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` does not turn hex code into the corresponding bytes in the way you were thinking.

Because you had 64 characters in that string, you get 64 bytes of UTF-8 bytes. That's a 512-bit-long bitstream.

Comment: Is there a framework method to convert an hex string to byte[]?

Comment: Thanks, that sorted it - much appreciated.