# ASP.NET Rijndael Decryption Error: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid

Tags: asp.net, encryption, cryptography, rijndaelmanaged

OK, so having [just got the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835896/asp-net-rijndael-encryption-error-specified-key-is-not-a-valid-size-for-this-al) to be accepted and have an encrypted string out which is 44 char long, I now am unable to decrypt (aarrgghh):

***Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.***

Having looked around and read various posts it looks as though the conversion to a Base64String may be the problem but I can't see where it is wrong - many of the solutions I have seen appear to be identical to what I have. Again, I'd really appreciate any help - extracts below:

Encryption/Decryption Function

```
Private byteKey As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("B499F4BF48242E05548D1E4C8BB26A2E")
Private byteIV As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(",%u'm&'CXSy/T7x;4")

Private Function Rijndael(ByVal sInput As String, ByVal bEncrypt As Boolean) As String
    ' Create an instance of encyrption algorithm. 
    Dim _rijndael As New RijndaelManaged()
    ' Create an encryptor using key and IV - already available in byte() as byteKey and byteIV
    Dim transform As ICryptoTransform
    If bEncrypt Then
        transform = _rijndael.CreateEncryptor(byteKey, byteIV)
    Else
        transform = _rijndael.CreateDecryptor(byteKey, byteIV)
    End If
    ' Create streams for input and output 
    Dim msOutput As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    Dim msInput As New CryptoStream(msOutput, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    ' Feed data into the crypto stream. 
    msInput.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sInput), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sInput).Length)
    ' Flush crypto stream. 
    msInput.FlushFinalBlock()
    Dim byteOutput As Byte() = msOutput.ToArray
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(byteOutput)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim sEncrypted As String = Rijndael("This is a test", True)
Dim sDecrypted As String = Rijndael(sEncrypted, False) **This is the line where it is crashing**
```

**EDIT - Final, seemingly working pair of functions (see comment) for ref:**

```
Private byteKey As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("B499F4BF48242E05548D1E4C8BB26A2E")
Private byteIV As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(",%u'm&'CXSy/T7x;4")

Public Function Encrypt(ByVal sInput As String) As String
    ' Create an instance of our encyrption algorithm. 
    Dim _rijndael As New RijndaelManaged()
    ' Create an encryptor using our key and IV 
    Dim transform As ICryptoTransform
    transform = _rijndael.CreateEncryptor(byteKey, byteIV)
    ' Create the streams for input and output 
    Dim msOutput As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    Dim msInput As New CryptoStream(msOutput, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    ' Feed our data into the crypto stream 
    msInput.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sInput), 0, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sInput).Length)
    msInput.FlushFinalBlock()
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(msOutput.ToArray)
End Function

Public Function Decrypt(ByVal sInput As String) As String
    ' Create an instance of our encyrption algorithm. 
    Dim _rijndael As New RijndaelManaged()
    ' Create an encryptor using our key and IV 
    Dim transform As ICryptoTransform
    transform = _rijndael.CreateDecryptor(byteKey, byteIV)
    ' Create the streams for input and output 
    Dim msOutput As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    Dim msInput As New CryptoStream(msOutput, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    ' Feed our data into the crypto stream. 
    msInput.Write(Convert.FromBase64String(sInput), 0, Convert.FromBase64String(sInput).Length)
    msInput.FlushFinalBlock()
    Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msOutput.ToArray)
End Function
```

Usage

```
Dim sEncrypted As String = Encrypt("This is a test")
Dim sDecrypted As String = Decrypt(sEncrypted)
```

Comment: This is one of the cases where a boolean parameter is telling you that this is really two different routines -- in this case routine 1 needs to be run backwards to make routine 2.

Comment: In retrospect a very fair comment, given the variance between the two since the fix - orginally (and erroneously) there wasn't much which is why it was like that - I live and learn. Upvote on the comment for what its worth! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer, I appreciate it. The problem for me, like yours, was that I switched the `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` and `Convert.ToBase64String()` around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're going to convert it to base64 you're going to have to decode it using Base64. At the moment you're taking the output Base64 byte array then using UTF8 to convert it back to bytes, which gives you a completely different value.

You should be using [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) instead of UTF8 for changing the string to bytes when decoding, then using UTF8 instead of Base64 for interpreting the data.

EG: On the decode you'd want

```
msInput.Write(Convert.FromBase64String(sInput), 0, Convert.FromBase64String(sInput).Length)
```

And for the return when decoding:

```
Return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteOutput)
```